# How do you properly use paging with only a local database in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, paging, android-paging, android-paging-3

I just recently began learning about paging in Android and completed Google's beginner tutorial that shows how to use paging with local code only, not using a Room database. The next tutorial from Google shows how to use paging with data from a network as well as a database. I know the third option is to simply use a local database without the use of network data, but I have put about 20+ hours into trying to figure this out over the past few days and have searched everywhere with no answer. When I run the code that I have posted below, I just get an empty recyclerview. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

PagingSource Class:

```
private const val INITIAL_START_KEY = 0

class ProductPagingSource(val productList: List<Product>): PagingSource<Int, Product>() {
private fun ensurePositiveValue(key: Int) = max(key, INITIAL_START_KEY)

override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Product>): Int? {
    val anchorPosition = state.anchorPosition ?: return null
    val article = state.closestItemToPosition(anchorPosition) ?: return null
    return ensurePositiveValue(article.id - (state.config.pageSize / 2))
}

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Product> {
    val start = params.key ?: INITIAL_START_KEY

    val range =  start.until(start + params.loadSize)

    val currentPage: List<Product> = productList.subList(range.first, range.last)
    Log.d("List", "$productList")

        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = currentPage,

            prevKey = when(start) {
                INITIAL_START_KEY -> null
                else -> ensurePositiveValue(range.first - params.loadSize)
            },

            nextKey = range.last + 1
        )
}
}
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertProduct(product: Product)

@Query("SELECT * FROM product_items ")
fun getProductList(): PagingSource<Int, Product>

@Query("SELECT * FROM product_items WHERE id = :id")
fun getProductById(id: Int): Flow<Product>

@Query("DELETE FROM product_items")
fun deleteAll()
}
```

Repository:

```
class ProductRepository(
private val dataAccess: ProductDao,
private val server: ProductApi
) {

suspend fun retrieveAndStoreProducts() {
    val response = server.retrofitService.gatherProducts()
    val data = response.products
    dataAccess.deleteAll()
    for (i in data) {
        dataAccess.insertProduct(i)
    }
}

fun getAllProducts(): PagingSource<Int, Product> {
    return dataAccess.getProductList()
}

fun getProductDetails(id: Int): Flow<Product> {
    return dataAccess.getProductById(id)
}
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private const val ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 5

class ProductViewModel(private val repository: ProductRepository): ViewModel() {

init {
    gatherAndStoreData()
}

private fun gatherAndStoreData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            repository.retrieveAndStoreProducts()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("REPOSITORY", "Error gathering data from server")

        }
    }
}

val itemsPage: Flow<PagingData<Product>> = Pager(
    config = PagingConfig(pageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE, enablePlaceholders = false),
    pagingSourceFactory = { repository.getAllProducts() }
)
    .flow
    .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

PagingDataAdapter:

```
class ProductAdapter(
val onClick: () -> Unit
) : PagingDataAdapter<Product, ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>(DiffCallBack) {


class ProductViewHolder(private val binding: ItemViewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(product: Product) {
        binding.product = product
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        determineStars(product.rating)
    }

    private fun determineStars(rating: Double) {
        var image: ImageView
        for(i in 1..5) {
            image = when(i) {
                1 -> binding.starOne
                2 -> binding.starTwo
                3 -> binding.starThree
                4 -> binding.starFour
                else -> binding.starFive
            }

            if(rating > i) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_rate_24)
            } else if (rating < i && (rating + .5) >= i ) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_half_24)
            } else {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_outline_24)
            }
        }

    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder {
    return ProductViewHolder(
        ItemViewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentProduct = getItem(position)
    if (currentProduct != null) {
        holder.bind(currentProduct)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onClick() }
    }
}

object DiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
}
```

Use in Fragment:

```
class ProductListFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: ProductViewModel

private lateinit var adapter: ProductAdapter

private lateinit var binding: FragmentProductListBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentProductListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val dao = ProductDatabase.getInstance(requireContext()).productDao
    val api = ProductApi
    val repository = ProductRepository(dao, api)
    val factory = ProductViewModelFactory(repository)
    viewModel = factory.create(ProductViewModel::class.java)

    adapter = ProductAdapter() {
        val action = ProductListFragmentDirections.actionProductListFragmentToProductDetailFragment()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
    val recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.itemsPage.collectLatest {
            adapter.submitData(it)
        }
    }
}

}
```